# Scanning through a string with regex and return exact value(s)

Tags: ruby, regex

The following shows a basic way to return all vowels in a string.

```
x = "I love Ruby".scan(/[aeiou]/)
```

If I assigned the matching keywords to a variable, would I be able to accomplish the same result shown above? I tried this but it seems not to work:

```
y = %w[bus car truck]
"I drive a bus most times but I have a truck".scan(/[#{y}]/) { |z| puts z }
```

I want to match and return exact values only.

Comment: You were quite close: `puts "I drive a bus most times but I have a truck".scan(/#{y.join('|')}/)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Regexp::union`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Regexp.html#method-c-union) should work:

```
Regexp.union(y)
#=> /bus|car|truck/

"I drive a bus most times but I have a truck".scan(Regexp.union(y))
#=> ["bus", "truck"]
```

The regular expression does not respect word boundaries. This may or may not be desired.

Comment: That's the one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
y = Regexp.new %w[bus car truck].join ?|
#=> /bus|car|truck/

"I drive a bus most times but I have a truck".scan y
#=> ["bus", "truck"]
```

Comment: That is a nice answer. Thanks for your contribution but Stefan's matches what I exactly wanted. ;)